# What is the correct way to use CFontDialog common dialog?

Tags: mfc

I recently change the relationship between the window extent and the view port  of an MFC application, and, since then, every time I change my application font size, the selected font become supper gigantic even if I chose the smallest of all font size.

(EDIT: I noticed that `CFontDialog::GetSize()` return a size that is ten times the size chosen in the dialog. Is that a usual behaviour ? If not what could make the dialogue return such a value? Although I am not sure, but it seem this multiplication of size seem to be my problem. How do I get `CFontDialog::GetSize()` to return the actual selected size, if that indeed is the problem?)

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to use `CFontDialog` ?

Shown next is a snippet of the font changing code:

```
CClientDC dc(pView);
pView->OnPrepareDC(&dc)

pLastFont = pLastText->GetFont();
oldColor = pLastText->GetColor();

LOGFONT logFont = (LOGFONT) (*pLastFont);
CFontDialog fontDialog(&logFont);

CSize szPrevSize;

//Some missing codes
MyFigure *pMyFigure;

if(dynamic_cast<MyTextFigure*>(pMyFigure) != NULL)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<MyTextBoxFigure*>(pLastText) != NULL)
    {
        MyTextBoxFigure *pTextBox = dynamic_cast<MyTextBoxFigure*>(pLastText);
        szPrevSize = pTextBox->GetTextSize();
    }
}
else if(dynamic_cast<MyTableFigure*>(pMyFigure) != NULL)
{
    MyTableFigure *pTableFigure = dynamic_cast<MyTableFigure*>(pMyFigure);
    TCell *pCell = (TCell *)*pTableFigure;
    szPrevSize = pCell->GetTextSize();
}

    fontDialog.m_cf.rgbColors = (COLORREF) oldColor;
if (fontDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
{

      fontDialog.GetCurrentFont(&logFont);
      MyFont newFont = (MyFont) logFont;
      MyColor newColor = (MyColor) fontDialog.GetColor();
      pMyFigure->SetFont(newFont, &dc);
      pMyFigure->SetColor(newColor);

}
```

Please note that `MyFont` is a wrapper around the `LOGFONT` structure and has an operator that enable cast to `LOGFONT`. Also note that `MyFigure` class has a `MyFont` data member that is set by the member function `SetFont`.

The following code shows how the relationship between the view port and the window extent was set.

```
void CDisplayView::OnInitialUpdate()
{

    CRect rcClient;
    GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    CClientDC dc(this);

    dc.SetMapMode(MM_ISOTROPIC);

    CSize szWindow(m_pAppDoc->GetZoomRatio() * SCALE_RATIO * dc.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES),m_pAppDoc->GetZoomRatio() * SCALE_RATIO * dc.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES));
    CSize szViewport(dc.GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES),dc.GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES));

    dc.SetWindowExt(szWindow);
    dc.SetViewportExt(szViewport);

    dc.DPtoLP(&rcClient);


    //And so on
}
```

`ZoomRatio` is 1, an  `SCALE_RATIO` is 1.2

The assignment operator is:

```
MyFont& MyFont::operator=(const MyFont& font)
{
   if (this != &font)
   {
      m_logFont = font.m_logFont;
   }

   return *this;
}
```

P.S. 
The summary of the code is:

```
LOGFONT OldlogFont ;
LOGFONT newLogFont;

COLLORREF OldColorref;
COLORREF newColorref;

CFontDialog fontDialog(&OldlogFont);
fontDialog.m_cf.rgbColors = oldColorref;

if (fontDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
  fontDialog.GetCurrentFont(&OldlogFont);
  newLogFont = OldlogFont;
  newColorref = fontDialog.GetColor();
}
```

The focus here is the `LOGFONT` structure.
The user selected value is gotten with old logfont then assigned to new logfont.

For debugging purposes, I retrieved the size of the selected font and was shocked to find that it is ten times the size that I selected after lunching the `CFontDialog` for use in my application i.e

```
LOGFONT OldlogFont ;
LOGFONT newLogFont;

COLLORREF OldColorref;
COLORREF newColorref;

CFontDialog fontDialog(&OldlogFont);
fontDialog.m_cf.rgbColors = oldColorref;

if (fontDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
  fontDialog.GetCurrentFont(&OldlogFont);
  newLogFont = OldlogFont;
  newColorref = fontDialog.GetColor();

   int iFontSize = fontDialog.GetSize();
   //when I selected a font size of 10 from the dialog, what I get   here in my code is 100.
}
```

Comment: Would it be totally irrational to suspect some sort of defect hiding inside `MyFont newFont = (MyFont) logFont;`?

Comment: I don't think the error is from that, but I will add codes the relevant MyFont members in case I am missing some thing.

Comment: What is `pLastText`? And the line `pMyFigure->SetFont(newFont, &dc);` doesn't make sense because `pMyFigure` isn't a pointer. Basically, there is not enough information to understand what your code is doing. You are using undeclared variables and undefined classes and methods. We have no idea what they do or how they are supposed to be used.

Comment: pMyFigure is a pointer, That was a type. See the code is some how complex and I cant possible show the declaration of the classes here.

Comment: That's why you are asked to provide a [mcve]. We do not want or need to see **all** your code. We need to see the most minimal code required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @llnspectable , it turns out you were some how right. I eventually found out that another member of the MyFont class carries out a last minute conversion from points to the desired unit before final display. The conversion resulted to a great enlarging of the font in the current map of logical unit to device unit as opposed to what opposed in the last mapping. Thanks you gave me the much needed clue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
void CExportSettingsDlg::OnBtnSelectFont()
{
    CClientDC   dc(this);

    m_plfCurrentFont->lfHeight =
        -MulDiv(m_plfCurrentFont->lfHeight, dc.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY), 72);

    CMyFontDialog   dlgFont( m_plfCurrentFont );

    dlgFont.m_cf.Flags |= CF_NOSCRIPTSEL;
    dlgFont.m_cf.rgbColors = m_crCurrentFontColour;

    if( dlgFont.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        m_plfCurrentFont->lfHeight = -(dlgFont.GetSize()/10);

        // We must retrieve the font colour into the correct variable.
        // The logfont is already correct because we passed in the
        // logfont pointer into the font dialogue.
        switch( m_iFontType )
        {
        case FONT_TITLE:
            m_sSettings.crTitleFontColour = dlgFont.GetColor();
            break;
        case FONT_HEADING:
            m_sSettings.crHeadingFontColour = dlgFont.GetColor();
            break;
        case FONT_GENERAL:
            m_sSettings.crGeneralFontColour = dlgFont.GetColor();
            break;
        case FONT_EVENT:
            m_sSettings.crEventFontColour = dlgFont.GetColor();
            break;
        case FONT_NOTES:
            m_sSettings.crNotesFontColour = dlgFont.GetColor();
            break;
        }

        // Update display
        SetSampleFont();

        // Html Preview
        UpdatePreviewHtml();
    }
}
```

If it does not answer your question I will remove the answer. Notice how I set the font size at the start of the code.

If you read up on the MSDN for [GetSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0akx347(v=vs.120).aspx) it states:

> The font's size, in tenths of a point

Comment: Why did you divide the value reurned by GetSize() by 10?

Comment: Ok. I see your comment below. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @user2779124 You are welcome. If you click the link you can read more.